# PHP excel reader cannot read excel file from command prompt

Tags: php, excel

I have an application that need to read excel file. I have already done this using a plugin excel-file-reader from http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list.
Now i need my application to read an excel file in a background process, and i choose to run the php file from windows command prompt.but when i do this, the result in command prompt is The filename person2.xls is not readable, but when i run the php file from the browser, it can read the excel file. here is my code to help you understand what i mean.

```
<?php
require_once 'php-excel-reader\excel_reader2.php';
$db=pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=hris user=postgres password=Abcd1234');
$table='lin_people';
$dataExcel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader('person2.xls');
$baris = $dataExcel->rowcount($sheet_index=0);
$model=$table;
$fieldsArray=pg_query('SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name="'.$model.'"');
//$fieldsArray=Set::extract('/0/'.$model,$fieldsArray);
$fieldNames=array_keys($fieldsArray[0][$model]);
$tanda=false;
for($batas=0;$batas<count($fieldNames);$batas++)
{
    if($fieldNames[$batas]!='id')
    {
        if($tanda==false)
        {
            $fields[$batas]=$fieldNames[$batas];
        }
        else
        {
            if($batas!=count($fieldNames)-1)
            {
                $fields[$batas]=$fieldNames[$batas+1];
            }   
        }
    }
    else
    if($fieldNames[$batas]=='id')
    {
        $fields[$batas]=$fieldNames[$batas+1];
        $tanda=true;
    }
}

$sukses = 0;
$gagal = 0;

for($i=2;$i<=$baris;$i++)
{
    if(!empty($dataExcel))
    {
        $this->$model->create();
        for($y=0;$y<count($fields);$y++)
        {
            if($y==0)
            {
                pg_query('INSERT INTO '.$model.' ('.$fields[$y].') VALUES("'.$dataExcel->val($i,$y+1).'")');
            }
            else
            {
                $currID=pg_query('SELECT id FROM '.$model.' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1');
                pg_query('INSERT INTO '.$model.' ('.$fields[$y].') VALUES("'.$dataExcel->val($i,$y+1).'") WHERE id='.$currID);
            }
                            //$this->$model->set($fields[$y],$dataExcel->val($i,$y+1));
        }
    }
                    //$this->$model->save();
    if('dataExcel')
    {
        $sukses++;
    }
    else
    {
        $gagal++;
    }

}
```

?>

How can i made this php file read an excel file when I run the php file from command prompt?please help me...

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help. I have a feeling it is 1 of two things:

1. File permissions.
2. Unrecognized Mime type.

Its probably the second one but here are 2 solutions:

```
chmod("person2.xls",0777);
$dataExcel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader('person2.xls');
chmod("person2.xls",0644);
```

If that doesn't work you may need to include a [mime type library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mime-magic.php).

Comment: when i run chmod as your advice, the result is Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\andro\testExcel.p
hp on line 4. but the file of person2 is already exists in same directory with the php file, but the result says that the file cannot be found.what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Command prompt uses other character encoding (character format) than Windows. Maybe this is where your problem resides. If you try to save an Excel spreadsheet as CSV or TEXT for example, you will find 2 filetypes: One for windows and one for DOS.

Hope that it helps...